# Can't connect symfony 2.1.2 to memcache to store sessions

Tags: session, symfony, memcached

I'm trying to host my sessions in memcache server using sf2 framework.
here is the config I have :
in config.yml

```
framework:
    ...
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.mc
...
services:
    session.memcache:
        class: Memcache
        calls:
            - [addServer , [%session_memcache_host%, %session_memcache_port%]]
    session.handler.mc:
        class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MemcacheSessionHandler
        arguments: [@session.memcache]
```

and in parameters I've set up my info like that :

```
session_memcache_host: memcachesession.lan
session_memcache_port: 11211
```

in my controller I have this :

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $session = new Session();
    $session->start();
    var_dump($session->getId());
    $session->set('foo','bar');
    $session->save();
    var_dump(session_id());
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    return array('name' => 'test');
}
```

And still I don't have my session in memcache ... I can't figure out why.
Any help would appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I got same problem. It can be cused by NativeSesionHandler Interface problems. They're planning to remove those handlers in Symfony2.2

Comment: Actually I'm not that sure of it ... but seems like the prefix part in MemcacheSessionHandler seems to break it. I've override it in order to remove the prefix part and seems like it's ok.

Comment: I don't know how to clear it from my config.yml ... how do you set an empty string ?

Comment: Well yes it was that ... by default sf2 will prefix all with sf2s_ that's why i can't find it in my other application.

Answer (score 1):

```
services:
session.memcache:
    class: Memcache
    calls:
        - [addServer , [%session_memcache_host%, %session_memcache_port%]]
session.handler.mc:
    class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MemcacheSessionHandler
    arguments: [@session.memcache, {prefix: ""}]
```

The main point here was to set an empty prefix ... so I have my real session name ... the one I have in my others application. Everything is ok now